# Embed Tweet in a .cshtml file

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to embed a tweet in .cshtml page side. For example;

```
<blockquote class="twitter-tweet" data-lang="tr"><p lang="tr" dir="ltr">“Biz rızkı her daim Hak’tan biliriz.&quot; <a href="t.co/j0OKkd2M7S">pic.twitter.com/j0OKkd2M7S</a></p>&mdash; Diriliş  **(@DirilisDizisi)**  <a href="https://twitter.com/DirilisDizisi/status/799207152694898688">17 Kasım 2016</a></blockquote>
```

There is a @ symbol at the beginning username and as you know @ symbol is a private key and I get an error as;

> The name 'DirilisDizisi' does not exist in the current context

How can i embed a tweet with @userName ?

Comment: @@ - the first escapes the second

Comment: Thank you, It is my solution.